# Download secrets <keyvault> prejob fails in ADO pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

We have a CI pipeline in Azure DevOps which requires to download secrets from the keyvault.
There is a service connection set up where a SP is used to connect to the Azure Portal. The SP has the necessary rights to reach the AKV and download the secrets.
The pipeline is running on a self hosted build agent's docker container.
The problem is that sometimes the pipeline fails on the first prejob called
Download secrets: 
This is the error what we get:

```
Starting: Download secrets: <keyvault>
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure Key Vault
Description  : Download Azure Key Vault secrets
Version      : 1.226.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault
==============================================================================
##[error]Unhandled: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/azp/_work/_temp/.taskkey'
##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/azp/_work/_temp/.taskkey'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:590:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:458:35)
    at Vault.getKey (/azp/_work/_tasks/<keyvault>/1.226.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/vault.js:62:22)
    at Vault.retrieveSecret (/azp/_work/_tasks<keyvault>/1.226.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/vault.js:49:28)
    at getInput (/azp/_work/_tasks/<keyvault>/1.226.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/task.js:224:27)
    at Object.getBoolInput (/azp/_work/_tasks/<keyvault>/1.226.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/task.js:253:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/azp/_work/_tasks/<keyvault>/1.226.0/task-runner.js:20:36)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /azp/_work/_tasks/<keyvault>/1.226.0/task-runner.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
Finishing: Download secrets: <keyvault>
```

This error is not happening every time that makes the problem hard, it not consistantly reproduceable.
Did anyone had this problem and have a solution for it?

Comment: What region is your vault in? Do you see any corresponding errors in Azure Monitor reports for that vault? Off hand, the error looks like either a service error returned to the client or, more likely, a client error.